# Is it proper or redundant to use both the words "institute" and "college" together in naming an educational institution?

Tags: word-usage

Is it right to use the words "institute" and "college" in naming an educational institution namely "Institute of Public Policy & Leadership College"?. It is an affiliated institution/college under a university.

It seems to me that one word is enough and the other is redundant.

I am not an English native.

Comment: It might be two institutions. Namely the "Institute of Public Policy" and the "Leadership College", which is a part of said institute.

Comment: It's definitely redundant, like the [Department of Redundancy Department](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Department_of_Redundancy_Department)

Comment: However, you could use: https://batten.virginia.edu/ *X School of Leadership and Public Policy.

Comment: Please include a link to the same question that you posted on ELU. That question should also link here. Doing so helps people to be aware of similar questions so that they can see the entire discussion & answers.

Comment: Please **do not cross post**.

Comment: I posted here as suggested in the other forum. Sorry.

Comment: The news item says, "In the first stage, KILA will start Institute of Public Policy and Leadership PG College...." and it is there at https://www.newindianexpress.com/states/kerala/2022/jun/06/leadership-crash-course-for-politicians-public-figures-bykila-2462179.html

Answer (score 1):

This title probably means:

> Institute of Public Policy

> and

> Leadership College

If not, yes I agree that having these two words together in the same title is redundant. They are both quite similar in meaning!